# Trying to ignore zero values in Excel column

Tags: excel, pandas, python-2.7

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4k5J.png)In an Excel spreadsheet I am working on there are two columns of interest, column B and column E. In column B there are some 0 values and these are getting carried over to the column E based on the loop that I am running with respect to column D. I want to write a Python script to ignore these 0's and pick the next highest value based on their frequencies into column E.

```
           12NC ModifiedSOCwrt12NC              SOC
0  232270463903                  0                0
1  232270463903                  0                0
2  232270463903                  0                0
3  232270463903                  0                0
4  232270463903                  0  RC0603FR-0738KL
5  232270463903                  0  RC0603FR-0738KL
6  232270463903                  0  RC0603FR-0738KL
```

I want to run a loop which picks non-zero values from SOC (column B) and carries it over to ModifiedSOCwrt12NC (column E) based on unique values in Column D.

For example, Column B has values = [0, RCK2] in multiple rows which are based on unique values in column D. So the current loop picks the maximum occurrences of values in column B and fills it into column E. If there is a tie between occurrences of 0 and RCK2, it picks 0 as per the ASCII standard (which I don't want to happen). I want the code to pick RCK2 and fill those in column E.

Comment: please don't put input as image, it's hard to reproduce your input. please provide expected result.

Comment: I want to run a loop which picks non-zero values from column B and carries it over to Column E based on unique values in Column D.

Comment: I'm not getting what you are saying, It's really unclear to me. How you are iterating your rows? what do you mean carries here? do you want to replace the values from column B to Column D where Column B is 0? Please provide Sample Input and Output

Comment: For ex: Column B has values = [0, RCK2] in multiple rows which is based on unique values in column D. So the current loop picks the maximum occurrences of values in column B and fills it into column E. If there is a tie between occurrences of 0 and RCK2, it picks 0 as per the ASCII standard (which I don't want it to happen). I want the code to pick RCK2 and fill those in the column E. Hope this makes it little more clearer.

Comment: sorry I didn't get you, I don't understand why are you not spending your time to edit the question with much cleaner way? your question is unclear. please provide Sample Input and Output in your question section.

Comment: @roht20 based on the data can you also post an expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Data is not accessible, I have created a test data similar to one below -

[image]

We can read data in pandas -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("ExcelTemplate.xlsx")
df

Index   SOC Index2  12NC
0   YXGMY   0   ZJIZX   23445
1   NQHQC   0   JKJKT   23445
2   MWTLY   0   EFCYD   23445
3   RPQFE   AC  VLOJZ   23445
4   GPLUQ   AC  AKKKG   23445
5   WGYYM   AC  DSMLO   23445
6   XGTAQ   0   ZHGWS   45667
7   AMWDT   0   YROLO   45667
```

following code will do the summarization -

1. First summarize data on 12NC and SOC and take count
2. Sort by 12NC, count and SOC, with highest count first
3. Take the first value of SOC for each 12NC
4. Merge with original Data to create column E
5. Export back to Excel

```
df1 = df.groupby(['12NC', 'SOC'])['Index'].count().reset_index()
df = df.merge(df1[df1['SOC']!=0].sort_values(by=['12NC', 'Index', 'SOC'], ascending=[True, False, True])\
         .drop_duplicates(subset=['12NC'], keep='first')[['12NC', 'SOC']].\
         rename(index=str, columns={'SOC': 'ModifiedSOCwrt12NC'}),\
         on = ['12NC'], how='left')
df.to_excel("ExcelTemplate_modifies.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort you took to help me. Could you let me know how I can skip over a particular value such as 0 in this case and pick the next value which has the second highest occurrence in a loop.

Comment: In my code snippet, see where I have written - df1[df1['SOC'] !=0], this is to skip zeros, and can be used to skip any value